# <td> cannot appear as a child of `div`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am following this example https://codesandbox.io/s/little-star-yq2h8
which use state. Now I make the same example using `hooks`

but getting this error

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    in td (at editable-cell.js:34)
    in div (at editable-cell.js:56)
    in EditableCell (created by TableCell)
    in TableCell (created by TableRow)
    in tr (created by BodyRow)
    in BodyRow (created by TableRow)
    in TableRow (created by Connect(TableRow))
    in Connect(TableRow) (created by ExpandableRow)
    in ExpandableRow (created by Conne
```

and row view is not reflecting why ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-burnell-l504y

```
const PmViewList = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <EditableFormTable />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `editable-cell` component is returning this:

```
        <div>
            <EditableContext.Consumer>{renderCell}</EditableContext.Consumer>
        </div>
```

Meanwhile `renderCell` returns something like this:

```
               <td {...restProps}>
                   [cell contents]
               </td>
```

My experience with react is limited, but I'm guessing that means that your cell is going to produce HTML that has a `<div>` with a `<td>` inside of it, which is not valid. `<td>`s are only allowed inside of table-oriented elements like `<tr>`.

Simply removing those `<div>` tags appears to make things work:
[image]

Comment: You can wrap the EditableContent in a fragment <> to get rid of the adjacent JSX warning as well :)